# How to create Custom slash commands in rocketchat?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, rocket.chat

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as host and the version of Rocket.Chat That I use is 0.61.0.
I want to create custom slash commands in my rocket.chat server. Can anyone provide me a clue regarding how shall I do it??

Comment: According to this issue, this is not supported for now: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/6583

Comment: @Rohlik Thank you for the response.